# How to use Entra groups to set up team hierarchy as groups

Tags: microsoft-entra-id

I'm trying to find a good solution for implementing/managing a project's team structure with Entra.

The project has the following ideal hierarchy and I want to implement this somehow in Entra.

*members in parenthesis*

- The Project (PersonA, PersonB, PersonC, PersonD)

  - Application 1 (PersonA, PersonB, PersonC)

    - developers (PersonA, PersonC)
    - support (PersonB)

The ideal solution would hit the following goals

- When you delete a person from a group, they are automatically removed from the nested groups
- Any person in a nested group must also be a member of the parent groups

The two things I've come across are dynamic group memberships or [nested groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups#add-or-remove-a-group-from-another-group)